# Question on evaluation of a limit of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Find the following limit $:$
>
> $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac {1} {\sqrt {N}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {n}}.$$

It is quite clear that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {n}} \gt  \sqrt {N}$ for $N \gt 1.$ So the limit (if it exists finitely) has to be $\geq 1.$ But I believe that the limit is infinty. For that I need the sum to be greater than some scalar multiple of $N^s$ for sufficiently large $N$ where we require $s \gt \frac {1} {2}.$ Is it possible to attain this lower bound eventually? Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The limit is $2$. Use comparison with $\frac 1 {\sqrt N}\int_1^{N} \frac 1 {\sqrt x}dx$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy$:$ We have the following inequalities $:$ $$\frac {1} {\sqrt {N}} \left (1 + \int_{1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {x}}\ dx \right ) \geq \frac {1} {\sqrt {N}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {n}} \geq \frac {1} {\sqrt {N}} \int_{1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {x}}\ dx.$$ So by Sandwich theorem we have $$\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {1} {\sqrt {N}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {n}} = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}  \frac {1} {\sqrt {N}} \int_{1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {x}}\ dx = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {2 \sqrt {N} -  2} {\sqrt {N}} = 2.$$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: You can also consider the Riemann sum $\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{\sqrt\frac nN}$.

Comment: @nejimban$:$ This Riemann sum approximates to the integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac {1} {\sqrt {x}}\ dx$ for sufficiently large $N.$

Comment: Riemann sum works only for bounded functions in the needed integral. To achieve the correct answer, I think Kavi approach is needed. By the way, interesting question! I quite liked it. =)

Comment: The limit is indeed equal to 2. We can use simple bounds for the sum and then use Sandwich theorem to yield the result. I'll write down my answer. !)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it will be helpful to those who are not familiar with the technique mentioned above in the comment section. So, I am posting an answer.

By the definition of Riemann integrals, we know $\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\lim\limits_{N \to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (\frac{n}{N})$.

Also, $$\lim\limits_{N \to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt n}=\lim\limits_{N \to\infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \sqrt\frac{N}{n}=\lim\limits_{N \to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (\frac{n}{N}),$$
where $f(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt x}$.

Therefore:

$$\lim\limits_{N \to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt n}=\int_0^1  \frac {1}{\sqrt x}dx=2.$$

---

**Update:**

**As mentioned in the comments, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, so some explanation is required to justify the last step. Indeed, we should be more careful with the approximation sum.**

Note that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,1+a]$ for $a>0$, and in particular, let's assume $2-\epsilon<2\sqrt{1+a}-2\sqrt a$, where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real number. Hence, by the definition of Riemann integrals, we have:

$$2\sqrt{1+a}-2\sqrt a=\int_a^{1+a} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} dx=\int_a^{1+a} f(x) dx=\lim\limits_{N \to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (a+\frac{n}{N}).$$
So, by the definition of limit, there is $N_0 \in \mathbb N$, such that for every $N>N_0$, we have:

$$2\sqrt{1+a}-2\sqrt a-\epsilon <\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (a+\frac{n}{N})<2\sqrt{1+a}-2\sqrt a+\epsilon.$$

But for every $N$, we also have:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (a+\frac{n}{N})<\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (\frac{n}{N})=\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{n=1}^N 2(\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1})=2.$$

So, for $N>N_0:$

$$2\sqrt{1+a}-2\sqrt a-\epsilon<\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (\frac{n}{N})=\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt n}<2,$$

and:

$$2-\epsilon -\epsilon <2\sqrt{1+a}-2\sqrt a-\epsilon<\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f (\frac{n}{N})=\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt n}<2.$$

Comment: Some comments explaining why the integral converges to the correct sum should be added. Which theorem should be used to conclude that? Note that the function is not continuous at $0$, since $f$ is not defined there.

Comment: @R.W.Prado yes. Although $f(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt x}$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$, all the relations still work because $\int_a^1 f(x) dx$ exists as $a$ tends to zero.

Answer (score 4):

If you enjoy generalized harmonic numbers, you can have a good appromation os the partial sum
$$S_N=\frac {1} {\sqrt {N}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {\sqrt {n}}=\frac {1} {\sqrt {N}}\,H_N^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ and, using asymptotics
$$S_N=2+\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{N}}+\frac{1}{2 N}-\frac{1}{24
   N^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^4}\right)$$ Using this trucated series for $N=100$, you would obtain $1.858960382452$ while the exact value is
$1.858960382478$

Comment: More comments should be added explaining how to obtain these numbers and why the sum is not 2, as the others suggests.

Comment: @R.W.Prado. I computed and approximated the partial sum $S_N$. Now, if $N\to \infty$, the result is $2$.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use Cesàro-Stolz:
$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}} = \frac{1/\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ and this obviously converges to $2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly note that
$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = 2\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}) }{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}) }=\frac{2}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}) }<\frac{2}{2\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Similarly one can show that :
$$2(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}) >\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Clubbing the inequalities we have
$$2{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) }<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}) $$
Summing them up from $n=1$ to $n=N$ we get a telescopic sum and hence the inequality becomes :
$$ 2(\sqrt{N+1}-1)<\sum \limits_{n=1}^{n=N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2(\sqrt{N})$$
Now dividing by $\sqrt{N}$ yields
$$\frac{2(\sqrt{N+1}-1)}{\sqrt{N}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{n=N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2$$
Letting $N\to \infty $ and using sandwich theorem ,we get the required limit equal to 2. That is :

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{n=N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} =2$$